# Putty - Can't See Top of Error Stack Trace

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, putty

I am coding on Putty (in C++ for what it's worth) and I am currently encountering an error that gives me a really long stack trace. Apparently, the trace is so long that Putty won't let me scroll to the very top where it originated (where I typed "make"). Is there any way around this (except by obviously fixing the error)?

Comment: I really don't understand why this question was voted down or closed. I was under the impression that Putty fell into the category of "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: It's because this question isn't in any way unique to programming.  From your question, it seems doubtful that you understand what PuTTY actually is.  You can't code "on PuTTY".  You're writing code on a remote server, and PuTTY provides the connection.

Comment: The FAQ states "software tools commonly used by programmers", not "software tools exclusively used by programmers". And I understand perfectly well what Putty is - the "on Putty" vs "using Putty" is a pretty trivial semantic bone to pick.

Comment: I think that's recognition that many text editors are not exclusively used for programming, but some features in those editors are development-oriented (e.g. "Find References" to a variable, or syntax coloring).  Questions about features designed for use in programming are on-topic, even if they're part of a general purpose tool.  General-purpose features should be discussed on SuperUser.

Comment: I see plenty of Putty questions similar in scope to mine in the related list that are neither down voted nor closed. I can grant the closing, but was the down vote really necessary? The question was clear and I can see it being useful to someone.

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted.  I didn't, and don't agree with that.  Also please note that the questions which weren't closed are 3 years old (ish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways.

1. Change the Window buffer size. Open Putty, load the connection (don't double-click or hit open), click on `Window` on the left panel and increase the `Lines of scrollback` to something like 3000 (I think  the default is 200).
2. Same way, load the connection, and then on the left panel under Session you will have the sub-category `logging` where you can set a file where the entire session history will be recorded.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the lines of scrollback, before you make a putty connection, click on the category Window and increase the lines of scrollback to 10000 or 20000 as may suit you.